# In what way beautiful soup works differenty in fetching links?

Tags: python, string, url, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

Insted of using `beautiful soup` why is it not smart to get the html content and extract all links by finding all the instances of strings which starts with `<a href="`. 
What other way is there to extracting links if `beautiful soup` cannot be used?

Comment: Why `BeautifulSoup` cannot be used? What are the conditions you have? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it is not sufficient to look for links that start with

```
<a href="#">
```

There could be different variations of the hyperlink in the HTML utilising class, id or HTML5 data attributes like:

```
<a class="myclass id="the-id" data-tip="a tip" href="#">
```

Using Beautiful Soup would allow you to do this very simply in Python, especially if you have a background in HTML and CSS:

```
# src is the html of the web page.
soup = BeautifulSoup(src)

linkElements = soup.select('a.someclass')

if len(linkElements) > 0:
    for alinktag in linkElements:
        print alinktag['href']
```

In addition, if the HTML is in some tree structure like the following, Beautiful soup can easily extract the  elements out:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <a class="linkclass" href="http://www.google.com">first link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <a class="linkclass" href="http://www.yahoo.com">second link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Beautiful Soup code:

```
linkElements = soup.select('parent a.linkclass')
```

If you are looking for alternatives to Beautiful Soup in Python, there is a good discussion on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-Python-libraries-for-parsing-HTML-other-than-Beautiful-Soup).

Comment: If the counter question is not out of scope, i'd like to know how beautiful soup does that?

Comment: What do you mean by counter question?

Comment: That how does beautiful parse URL's avoiding all the `<a href="#` and what not.

Comment: I think Anzel has already answered that partially.  From Beautiful Soup documentation, "Beautiful Soup sits on top of popular Python parsers like lxml and html5lib".  Hence it does not actually use regex or string comparison. What it does is to parse the underlying XML or HTML structure, and then to read attributes or elements.  In the case of a hyperlink, the underlying parser reads the attribute of the <a> tag (see Anzel's example in using pure xml - "print a.attrib").

Comment: Edited answer on Beautiful Soup having a low learning curve for users with background in html and css.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps others may not like my answer, but **BeautifulSoup** isn't the only way to manipulate html content. And in fact **BeautifulSoup** itself **DOESN'T** do that, it's the underlying **HTML Parser** who does the job.

You can use **lxml** (even BeautifulSoup recommends it) or even just Python's standard library **xml** / html parser modules to parse the html content and manipulate it.

Take an example here that I took from @maskie (sorry because I am lazy to do a dummy):

Sample using **xml** module:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

s = '''<div class="parent">
           <div class="child">
               <a class="linkclass" href="http://www.google.com">first link</a>
           </div>
           <div class="child">
               <a class="linkclass" href="http://www.yahoo.com">second link</a>
           </div>
       </div>'''

html = ET.fromstring(s)

for a in html.findall('.//a[@class="linkclass"]'):
    print a.attrib

{'href': 'http://www.google.com', 'class': 'linkclass'}
{'href': 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'class': 'linkclass'}
```

You can simply get the html content from the web by using Python standard-library **urllib** or the excellent **requests** modules. I do web scraping quite often and most of the time I'm only using **requests** and **lxml** and they do the job beautifully.

**NO** you don't need **BeautifulSoup** to extract contents from html, I'd say it just makes manipulating html content in a much easier way (for some people).

And my answer is **YES** you can use any competent **HTML Parser** to manipulate html content like what you suggested and still get the job done.